# Magento: use 'validate-ajax' in forms?

Tags: jquery, validation, magento

I am having a custom form with captcha. Captcha is not a module / plugin, its just custom written by me. I want to validate captcha using the ajax(with out page refresh) with validate.js / varien form.js which is magento default validator. I have written jQuery.ajax functionality with validation.add(). My problem is, The validator() is not waiting for ajax respose (true / false) and it is taking the status as 'undefined' and showing the error.

I have pasted my code below:

```
Validation.add('validate-captcha', 'Please enter correct captcha', function (v) {
  var cp = isValidCaptcha();
  return cp;
});

function isValidCaptcha(){
  var captcha_value = jQuery("#security_code").val();
  var a = 0;
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('tqr/index/chkcaptcha'); ?>",
    asynchronous:true,
    data: { security_code1: captcha_value },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
      if( data == 1 ){
        a = 1;
      } else {
        a = 2;
      }                 
    }

  });

  if( a == 1 ){
   return true;
  } else if ( a == 2  ){
    return false;
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Basically your problem is, from what I understand, that your Validate function does not wait for the `isValidCaptcha()`.

In order to make 2 functions `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` to wait for each other, you would have to call them in the following way :

```
firstFunction(function(){
    secondFunction();
});
```

And in addition you would have to define a callback for the first function :

```
function firstFunction(callback){
    // do stuff here
    callback();
}

function secondFunction(){
     // do ajax call here
}
```

Your `firstFunction` is the Validate one, while your `secondFunction` is the `isValidCaptcha()` which makes the AJAX call.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response. I tried your idea, but the same error repeats. Can you please brief your suggestion?

Comment: If you know magento can you please let me how the method 'validate-ajax' works? This method located in js/prototype/validate.js

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Magento. I was giving a reply from a Javascript call mechanism point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a submit when the AJAX response comes back & the Prototype validator will run.